# How to add custom style on tailwind css class?

Tags: tailwind-css

*Tailwind CSS*

```
<div className='py-20' style={text-underline- offset:"auto"}>
```

Actually I'm trying to write text-offset on tailwind CSS class . But i'm confused about curly bracket , is curly bracket start with 2 start curly or one ?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use utility classes in tailwind? Why are you using inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
style={{text-underline- offset:"auto"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
style = {{height:'200'}};
```